# How compute frequency of signal from zero crossing?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, frequency

I need to compute frequency of a signal from zero crossing.It's possible to compute to frequency from zero crossing of a signal.
Plz anybody help me about this with matlab .

Answer (score 1):

From your signal crossing threshold it is fairly straightforward to calculate its period. When you know the period then calculating of corresponding frequency is very simple (its inverse). This answer: [enter here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4886/zero-crossing-of-a-noisy-sine-wave) answers to similar question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know that this will only work if you need to estimate frequencies in signals next to pure sinusoids, so for this a simple code can be used.

I create  a simple sin sampled at 8000hz and frequency at 350hz, lets try get  the frenquency using zero crossing method:

```
Fs = 8000;
f  = 350; %Frequency test
signal= 0.9*sin(2*pi*f/Fs*(0:2048));

%cross = sign(signal(:)); % you can test results using sign function too.
cross(signal==0) = 1;
index= find(diff(cross));
ZC = length(index);
F0_ZC=(ZC * Fs / (2 * (length(signal))))
```

The result was:

```
F0_ZC =

  349.4388
```

> Edit

The quick try using @jojek sugestion:

```
Fs = 8000;
f  = 350; %Frequency test
signal= 0.9*sin(2*pi*f/Fs*(0:2048));
ZCR = sum(abs(diff(sign(signal(:)))))/(2*length(signal));
F0_ZC=(ZCR * length(signal) * Fs) / (2 * (length(signal)))
```

The result was:

```
F0_ZC =

  350.4148
```

Course if you compute the Zero Crossing Rate(ZCR) you can find the frequency using `(ZCR  * Fs) /2`

Comment: The way you calculate ZCR is not robust at all. Definitely there are better ways of doing that. For example: `sum(abs(diff(sign(x))/(2*L)`

Comment: Nice tip @jojek, I try it seems nice !